# How do you launch Safari browser from within an iPad app?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ipad, safari

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [launch safari from iphone app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/822599/launch-safari-from-iphone-app)

How do you launch Safari browser from within an iPad app?

Answer (score 3):

Like this:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:yourURLHere]];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
NSURL *someHTTP_or_HTTPS_URL;
if ( [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL: someHTTP_or_HTTPS_URL] ) {
    // success
} else {
    // failure
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:yourURLHere]];

you can dial number too using this

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:@"tel://123245655];

enjoy..