# Launch browser from my application

Tags: iphone

I want to launch safari browser from my IOS app with an specific url when I press a button.

Is that possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [launch safari from iphone app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/822599/launch-safari-from-iphone-app)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"]];
```

Comment: -[LoginWindow linkWebPitjat:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x650b9f0

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[LoginWindow linkWebPitjat:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x650b9f0'

Comment: ok I found the problem, and is not related with UIApplication...silly of me.. thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Use this code for launching the URL in the Safari Browser,

```
NSString* url = @"http://example.com";

UIApplication* app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
[app openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can!

Use the `- (BOOL)openURL:(NSURL *)url` method of `UIApplication`. You can get an instance of `UIApplication` using the static method `+ sharedApplication`.

Comment: is it possible that I didnt have this method on my AppDelegate?

Comment: You're getting confused - I'm referring to the class UIApplication, of which your AppDelegate class is a delegate. These are two different classes, and thus in your program will be two different objects. Delegation is a relationship between classes and forms its own design pattern. I suggest you read about the delegation design pattern if this is confusing you.