# How to move the user to a URL in Safari

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, safari

I am making an app for a charity and Apple's review guidelines state that all donations must be made outside of the app in Safari, except for SMS donations, which we're not doing anyway. How do I make a button, that when tapped, goes to a specific URL in Safari? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"your.website.here"]];
```

And put it in an IBAction for your button.

There might be a problem connecting to your site try this:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURLWithString:@"your.website.here"];
if (![[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url])

NSLog(@"%@%@",@"Failed to open url:",[url description]);
```

They actually have a post on it here:

[How can I launch Safari from an iPhone app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/822599/launch-safari-from-iphone-app)

Comment: Awesome, didn't know it was that simple, thanks for your help!!

Comment: That doesn't work. Nothing happens. I put a NSLog in the IBAction as well, and while I saw the NSLog, the app just sits there and does nothing. Safari does not open.

Comment: @Jack: Check to make sure there isn't a problem with connecting to the website.

Answer (score 3):

You can use this code in button click event

[`[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString: @"your url"]];`

it automatically opens in safari