# HTTP links from a iPad web app open within the app rather than Safari.. Can I stop this?

Tags: ipad, web-applications

I have a web app - not a native app.  So it is completely written in HTML/JS/CSS.

I cannot find a way to force links to open in safari.  They simply open within the web app which traps users at the site with no way to go back.

Has anyone found a fix for this?  I am stumped!

Comment: possible duplicate of [launch safari from iphone app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/822599/launch-safari-from-iphone-app)

Comment: I checked that one earlier; the answer is assuming that the OP is building a UIApplication.  Unless I am completely mistaken, that is not usable in a straight HTML/JS web app.

Comment: @KevinDTimm the question is if web app launched from home screen can open a link in Safari rather than the web app's UI-less window. Good question.

Comment: Interesting - good luck, I'll be watching :)