# I want the href links in my simple help page to open in safari

Tags: html, ios, ios7, safari, mobile-safari

I am targeting iOS 7.0.4 as that is the current version.  I have a help page in my app that is just html.  I have links in there that go to our company website, but I don't want them to open in the app, I want to launch safari.

I tried everything in this question:
[How to open Safari from a WebApp in iOS 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18879631/how-to-open-safari-from-a-webapp-in-ios-7)

Nothing really works.

The link keeps opening in the app, which means there's no browser goodies, like a back button, or url bar, and even the pinch zoom seems all weird.

Here's the relevant line of html code:

```
<p style="font-family:arial;font-size:60px;">Visit us on the web at 
<a href="http://ourcompany.com" target="_xxx">ourcompany.com</a>
```

I tried numerous things in the `target` such as `"_new"`, `"_blank"` or just not having it at all.

This is the code that loads the html:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"capitalsHelp" ofType:@"html"];
    NSURL *targetURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:targetURL];
    [_webView loadRequest:request];
}
```

Comment: Will this help? [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11524805/how-to-open-the-url-in-safari-not-in-webview). You aren't making a webapp I don't think, so... try that?

Comment: No, it's just a simple html page I'm using for help.

Comment: Please post your current code.

Answer (score 1):

Supposing you are using a UIWebView to present html, you can do the following:

```
- (BOOL) webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
    if (navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked ) {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[request URL]];
        return NO;
    }

    return YES;
}
```

on the UIWebView's delegate.