# How to open any iOS App from my own App

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

What I want to do is open any iOS Application (Evernote, safari, Facebook, etc) from my own iOS application. For example, I have created my app with two simple buttons, the first one is named "Evernote" and the second one is named "Safari", so when I click on the "Evernote" button I want that the Evernote App launch on my iOS device, the same when I click on the "Safari" button I want that the button opens my Safari App. How can I do that? It is that possible? If it is, please tell me how. Thank you very much.

Comment: use URL Scheme https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007899-CH1-SW1

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/419119/launch-an-app-from-within-another-iphone

Comment: Thank you very much, Cloudycliff!

Comment: Thank you, Sangony! That helps me a lot!

Answer (score 5):

yes it possible if you known this app scheme reference URL.
Example call Tel app:

```
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"tel://"]]){
     NSString *tell = [@"tel://" stringByAppendingString:phoneNumber];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:tell]];
}
```

Safari and other is same way.

List common schemes Url here : http://wiki.akosma.com/IPhone_URL_Schemes

Comment: launch safari http://stackoverflow.com/questions/822599/launch-safari-from-iphone-app.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this link helps you.

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-sdk-working-with-url-schemes--mobile-6629

If you need to open external apps from your app then follow the above link. Or if you need to open the iOS native apps like phone, mail, safari, etc, you can use URL schemes for opening the app.

Comment: Can you please click the check mark to right if the answer that helped you.. Thanks..