# Launch browser from custom keyboard iOS 8?

Tags: ios, ios8

Can I launch browser using custom keyboard in iOS8. I created custom keyboard and added an icon of browser. Now i want to launch browser when user tap on it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [launch safari from iphone app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/822599/launch-safari-from-iphone-app)

Comment: custom keyboard does not use its own application context but uses extension context, so I think not duplicate. Please reverify.

Comment: @ n00bProgrammer I want to launch browser from iOS 8 extension not from iPhone Application.

Comment: Anyone got the solution ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use below api from NSExtensionContext class.
Btw. the NSExtensionContext object represents the host app context from which an app extension is invoked.

```
- (void)openURL:(NSURL *)URL
completionHandler:(void (^)(BOOL success))completionHandler
```

Below is a sample:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com.com"];
NSExtensionContext *myExtension=[self extensionContext];
[myExtension openURL:url completionHandler:nil];
```

But there is a catch. 
Each extension point determines whether to support this method, or under which conditions to support this method.

So in that case you should use a WebView and load the request within it to redirect to the browser.

**Edit1:**

To redirect to safari from Webview try this:

```
-(BOOL) webView:(UIWebView *)inWeb shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)inRequest navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)inType {
        //[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[inRequest URL]];
          [myExtension openURL:url completionHandler:nil];
          return NO;

}
```

Also If you need to directly launch native app use predefined schemes like:

maps://

Comment: Thanks but I also want to open some apps to using URlScheme

Comment: Also can I test openUrl in iOS simulator??

Comment: custom uri scheme can also be used to handle other apps. Also simulator behaviour is well-defined for this scenario.

Comment: I tried like this :   NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://maps.apple.com/?daddr=San+Francisco,+CA&saddr=cupertino"];
    [webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]]; but it is not working. It is open link in webview. But if I open above link in Safari browser it opens Maps App.

Comment: elaborated more in the answer above as Edit.

Comment: i had tried above solution but in Keyboard it is not working. Please help if anyone got the solution.